# Ajax success call specific bootstrap tab

Tags: php, ajax

I am creating one small program in which Ι use two tabs in single page and call one ajax call to do operations dynamic.

Below is my code:

HTML Code below
        OffyApp Agents
        ListHub Agents

```
    <div id="Home" class="tabcontent">
    // Some code
    </div>

    <div id="News" class="tabcontent">
    // Some code
    </div>
```

Script Code Below

```
function openPage(pageName,elmnt,color) {
  var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
  tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
  for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
    tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablink");
  for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
    tablinks[i].style.backgroundColor = "";
  }
  document.getElementById(pageName).style.display = "block";
  elmnt.style.backgroundColor = color;
}
```

// Get the element with id="defaultOpen" and click on it
document.getElementById("defaultOpen").click();

AJax call Below

```
$.ajax({
url: "sendInvite.php",
type: "POST",
data: {list: inviteEmails},
                dataType: "JSON",
                beforeSend: function() {
                    $("#loading-image").show();
                 },
                success: function (data) {
                  //alert(data);
                    if (data.status == 200) {
                        alert("Invite Sent Successfully.");
                        location.reload(true);

                    }
                },
                error: function (msg) {
                    alert(msg);
                }
            });
```

If ajax call give me success then i want to redirect to my second tab like #News

Comment: You can trigger click with specific id of a tab after ajax request. For example if the tab id is "News" , you can trigger by using $("#News").trigger("click");

Answer (score 0):

```
success: function (data) {
       if (data.status == 200) {
           alert("Invite Sent Successfully.");
           location.reload(true);                   
    }}
```

`data.status` only will give you an error bacause neither data is JSON nor `data` have key `status`

Hence, your if statement is always false. `data` is the actual response as the plain text from the requested file. Therefore data have no such key like `status`.(eg.`data` is the `request.responseText`)

jQuery Ajax function has three variables:

```
success: function (a,b,c){}
```

Where:

`a` is the actual `responseText`

`b` is the `textStatus` &

`c` is `xhr`

Hence, you have to write success function as:

```
success: function (data,stxt,xhr){
    if(xhr.status==200){
        alert("Invite sent successfully!");
        window.location.reload();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could write a function

```
function activateTab(tab){
    $('.tab-pane a[href="#' + tab + '"]').tab('show');
};
```

Then upon success of your ajax call you can `activateTab('news');`

But as @Ritesh said, that function will not run because `data` does not contain a key called `success` on it, it will just contain the data you get from the server. You need to pass all the parameters into your success callback in order to access the response code.